# Open-Source Version Installation Problems

Tags: windows, qt, qt5, failed-installation

I am trying to install the open-sourced version of Qt using the web installer. It downloads everything and installs up to about 50% and then the errors start popping up. I get the following errors:

```
Error during installation process (qt.qt5.51Z5.win64_rnsvcZ0‘l5_64):
l Execution failed (Unexpected exit code: 2): "C:\Qt\/Tools/QtCreator\bin
\sdktool.exe addQt --id qt.qt5.5125.win64_msvc2015_64 --nameQt %{Qt::Version}
MSVC2015 64bit --type Qt4ProjectManager.Qt\Version.Desktop --qrnake C:\Qt/
5.12.5/msvc2015_64/bin/qrnake.exe"

Error during installation process (qt,qt5.5125.win64_msvc2015_64): 
Execution failed (Unexpected exit code: 2): "C:\QtVTools/QtCreator\bin 
\sdktool.exe addKit --id qt,qt5.5125.win64_msvc2015_64_kit --name Desktop Qt %(Qt:Version) MSVC2015 
64bit --Ctoolchain x86-windows-msvc2015-pe-64bit -­Cxxtoolchain x86-windows-msvc2015-pe-64bit --qt 
qt,qt5.5125.win64_msvc2015_64--debuggerengine4 --devicetype Desktop"

Error during installation process (qt,qt5.5125.win32_msvc2017): 
Execution failed (Unexpected exit code: 2): "C:\QtVTools/QtCreator\bin 
\sdktool.exe addQt --id qt.qt5.5125.win32_msvc2017 --name Qt %(Qt:Version} MSVC2017 32bit --type 
Qt4ProjectManager.QtVersion.Desktop --qmake C:\Qt/ 5.12. 5/msvc2017 /bin/ qmake.exe"

Error during installation process (qt,qt5.5125.win64_msvc2017_64): 
Execution failed (Unexpected exit code: 2): "C:\QtVTools/QtCreator\bin 
\sdktool.exe addQt --id qt.qt5.5125.win64_msvc2017_64 --name Qt %(Qt:Version} MSVC2017 64bit --type 
Qt4ProjectManager.QtVersion.Desktop --qmake Cc\Qt/ 5.12.5/msvc2017 _ 64/bin/ qmake.exe"

Error during installation process (qt,qt5.5125.win64_msvc2017_64): 
Execution failed (Unexpected exit code: 2): "C:\Qt\/Tools/QtCreator\bin 
\sdktool.exe addKit --id qt,qt5.5125.win64_msvc2017_64_kit --name Desktop Qt %(Qt:Version} MSVC2017 
64bit --Ctoolchain x86-windows-msvc2017-pe-64bit -­Cxxtoolchain x86-windows-msvc2017-pe-64bit --qt 
qt.qt5.5125.win64_msvc2017_64 --debuggerengine 4 --devicetype Desktop"
```

I have tried cancelling the install and then reinstalling it, I have tried redownloading the exe, but nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These errors are annoying. The installer is trying to run the `sdktool` to set up Qt build kits (compiler details/etc) in QtCreator, which it just installed, but can't, and the message never tells you why exactly.

In the past for me this has turned out to be a permissions problem -- the user `sdktool` is running as (from the Qt installer) doesn't have permissions to modify stuff in QtCreator installation folder. (Which I thought was strange since I always run everything as admin anyway.) So my solution has been to ensure the QtCreator install folder has write permissions for all Users on my system. Actually I just modify permissions on the whole Tools folder Qt installs.  This works (for me) even while the installer is running, after the first error prompt I can go in an change permissions and tell it to try again.

Another option is to ignore those errors and set up the compiler kits manually in QtCreator, but that's a hassle and it certainly helps get started when all that is set up for you already.

Another option would be copy those failed `sdktool` commands and run them manually after the installation.  I've done this a few times "in a pinch" but again it's a bit of a hassle.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try your suggestions. I marked this as answered.

Comment: This helped me too while installing and it gave an error like
Cannot download archive https://cdn.qt.io/qtsdkrepository/windows_x86/desktop/tools_maintenance/qt.tools.maintenance/42.0-0-202111081302tqtc-installer-framework-Windows-Windows_10-MSVC2015-Windows-Windows_10-X86-QtInstaller.7z: The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: It would be nice also to provide the modifying permission command that you've used.

Comment: @CroCo I use the Windows GUI to set permissions.  A "screeencast" with how to set permissions in Windows I thought was out of scope here since there are a myriad of guides to follow online if one needs it.  As mentioned I give all Users on the computer write permission to the Qt install _Tools_ folder and subfolders.  Others may want/need more granular permissions.

Comment: @MaximPaperno in my case (ubuntu 18.04), it seems the online installer forces me to install Qt Creator 7  which uses qt 6 (i.e. qt 6 is not compatible with 18.04 LTS).

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone else is having similar issues in Mac OS X with latest Qt6 and Qt Creator 4.14.
The sdktool path in the command is wrong. Manually create a symbol link in the Qt\ Creator.app/Contents/Resources/libexec/ (sdktool is in the parent folder of this), it should be working fine.

Comment: from this bug report: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-89966
I was able to run the suggested commands which mirror this answer to fix the issue:    
`cd "$HOME/Qt/Qt Creator.app/Contents/Resources/libexec/"`   
`ln -s ../sdktool`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. But my issues was due to having an old version of Qt Creator that had no libexec folder under $HOME/Qt/Qt Creator.app/Contents/Resources/. So I suggest updating Qt creator if you run into this.